# Opening a document programmatically in C++

Tags: c++

I have a console program written in C++. Now I want to open a manual document(in .txt or .pdf) everytime a user of the program types 'manual' in console. How can I do this? Any links to a tutorial would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Also, are you planning on writing the viewer yourself, or are you going to open a 3rd party viewer to display the document contents.  A few more details might help get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @James McNellis
I programmed it on windows but I'd also want to run it on linux machines. Can the code be platform independent? Where you just change the application parameter then recompile the source.
@Rob
I'm planning to open it using notepad on windows or gedit on linux.

Answer (score 8):

Try to compile this code (**Open.cpp**) to **Open.exe**
Then, you can execute it with (for example) these parameters :

**Open "C:\your file.doc"**

**Open "C:\your file.exe"**

**Open notepad**

```
#include "windows.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", argv[1], NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Explanation of the program :

1. You should first include windows
   library (**windows.h**) to get
   **ShellExecute** and **GetDesktopWindow** function.
2. **ShellExecute** is the function to execute the file with parameter
   **argv[1]** that is path to the file to be opened
3. Another option for `lpOperation`
   arguments instead of `"open"` is
   NULL. `"explore"` and `"find"` are
   also the options but they are not
   for opening a file.
4. **SW_SHOWNORMAL** is the constant to
   show the program in normal mode (not
   minimize or maximize)

Comment: Wouldn't using `start` be the same as your `open`?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, but we want to open a program/file without `dependency` for using `start` command

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're on Windows, you're looking for the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) function. (Use the "open" verb)

Answer (score 3):

In standard, platform independent, C and C++ you can use the `system` function to pass the name of an application to open your files.

For example, using Windows:

```
const char text_filename[] = "example.txt";
const char text_application[] = "notepad.exe";

std::string system_str;
system_str = text_application;
system_str += " ";
system_str += text_filename;

// Execute the application
system(system_str.c_str());
```

The text you send to the `system` function **is** platform specific.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It fails when I try to open a pdf file using adobe. It says "acrord32.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or program batch file".

Answer (score 1):

In Managed C++ is its very easy

System::Diagnostics::Process::Start(path);

done !